# In Mega Man Revolution, what effect does collecting all of the "MEGAMANR" letters have?

Tags: mega-man-revolution

In each of the eight main robot master stages of Mega Man Revolution, there is a collectible letter located in some part of the stage, usually requiring the use of an utility item and/or taking a harder stage route.

My question is, if one collects all eight of the characters ("M", "E", "G", "A", "M", "A", "N", and "R"), what effect does it have on the game? I have heard that it affects the ending but, I would like some confirmation on the matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find out how these letters affect the ending of the game [here](http://sprites-inc.co.uk/showthread.php?tid=1178) (I paraphrased the original post):

> Once you collect all the letters, it will be revealed that the self-insert doctor character is actually the bad guy, then you will need to go through another set of fortress stages, and then you will get to watch the self-insert doctor character turn into an alien.

If you want to avoid spoilers, then basically collecting all 8 letters will unlock the true final stages.